# Using the domain termination ".old" is causing web browsers to not detect that is a http/https server

Tags: https, http, domain-name, browser

I've created a virtual apache Server to host an old wordpress, everything went fine untill I tried to access the page via the domain on the browser.

When accessing the domain on the browser instead of loading the page it's trying to search the domain as a search on google.

[image: The unexpected behavior]

[image: The expected bahavior]

To temporarly fix this issue that I've found was writting `http://domain-used.old` to force it to redirect the browser to that url instead of searching it on google.

However, people are always complaining that they need to type the complete url (including the http/https) switching browsers keeps doing the same behavior (searching instead of loading).

In the end I had to re-deploy everything with a new domain ending that is not ".old".

**So is ".old" a limitation on the browsers, or is it a defined behavior that is defined in some RFC?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search suggests that there is no public  `.old`  top level domain / suffix.

At least I couldn't find it on :

- https://publicsuffix.org/list/
- http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

That probably results in your browser that `domain-used.old` isn't recognised as a FQDN, not forwarded to your systems resolver libraries and  instead treated a search string.